# The Poem of Love and Grace

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

Here is a simple poetry riddle I just thought up. Enjoy!

> A king, so great, lives fifteen years more,
> A giant, so mighty, his power so easily tore.
> A shepherd, in the wild, a stick to a snake,
> A death, so loving, causes the entire land quake.
> A man, so true, denial unfortunately he did,
> An apple, forbidden it was, a serpent sneakily slid.
> A boy, so wanted he was, a great ruler he become,
> Another king, so wise, a baby problem he made done.
> A light, so good, fallen to a mighty pharaoh,
> A elder, a big ship, sent some doves and crows.
> A boy, called to Him, so young,
> 3 more men held their tongue.
> An evil ruler he was, kill an innocent child,
> The little boy, so tender and mild.
> A man and a wall, helps make it stand,
> A queen, so brave, helps people across her land.
> A woman, so poor, had great luck with love,
> Another one, within a falling city, was saved, as sweet as a dove.
> Now you have heard, so tell me this,
> Who are these people, all ye Misters and Miss?

Comment: Abraham in the Bible I one of them

Comment: If you have an answer, make it a partial answer! I'd love to see what  you think

Comment: King Herod as well, it seems...

Comment: But I only got one...

Comment: It's ok! This is supposed to be one of those great riddles that take everyone! You know, like community wikis! That's a lot of people after all

Comment: Srry, I meant Moses

Comment: Please, don't make guesses in comments. If you have an answer (even just a **significant** partial answer) put it in an answer

Comment: I'm not sure this is much of a riddle as much as a direct reference. A knowledge tag seems necessary

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because each line appears to be general-reference from the Bible, with no puzzly obfuscation (such as wordplay). Additionally, since each line must be solved by itself, this puzzle invites many scattered answers - there isn't one final answer, just a collection of sub-answers. The combination, I believe, makes this puzzle a poor fit for our system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A king, so great, lives fifteen years more,

> Hezekiah - [Isaiah 38:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+38%3A5&version=CSB)

A giant, so mighty, his power so easily tore.

> Goliath - [1 Samuel 17:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2017%3A4&version=CSB) and [1 Samuel 17:50](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Samuel+17%3A50&version=CSB) or Samson - [Judges 16:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges+16%3A19&version=CSB) and [Judges 16:30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%2016%3A30&version=CSB)

A shepherd, in the wild, a stick to a snake,

> Moses - [Exodus 4:2-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+4%3A2-3&version=CSB)

A death, so loving, causes the entire land quake.

> Jesus - [Matthew 27:50-51](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+27%3A50-51&version=CSB)

A man, so true, denial unfortunately he did,

> Peter - [Matthew 26:69-75](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+26%3A69-75&version=CSB)

An apple, forbidden it was, a serpent sneakily slid.

> Satan (or the serpent), although technically it isn't specified to be an apple - [Genesis 3:1-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3%3A1-6&version=CSB)

A boy, so wanted he was, a great ruler he become,

> King David - [1 Samuel 20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2020&version=CSB), [1 Samuel 16:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Samuel+16%3A1&version=CSB), and [1 Samuel 16:12-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Samuel+16%3A12-13&version=CSB)

Another king, so wise, a baby problem he made done.

> Solomon - [1 Kings 3:6-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kings+3%3A6-9&version=CSB) and [1 Kings 3:16-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kings+3%3A16-28&version=CSB)

A light, so good, fallen to a mighty pharaoh,
Not sure about this one

A elder, a big ship, sent some doves and crows.

> Noah - [Genesis 7:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis+7%3A1&version=CSB), [Genesis 7:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+7%3A6&version=CSB), and [Genesis 8:6-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+8%3A6-8&version=CSB)

A boy, called to Him, so young,

> Samuel - [1 Samuel 3:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Samuel+3%3A10&version=CSB) and [1 Samuel 2:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Samuel+2%3A18&version=CSB)

3 more men held their tongue.

> The wise men (traditionally three because there were three gifts, but the passage doesn't specify how many there were) - [Matthew 2:7-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+2%3A7-8&version=CSB) and [Matthew 2:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+2%3A12&version=CSB)
>  Alternatively, Job's three friends, Eliphaz, Bildad, and Zophar - [Job 2:11-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job+2%3A11-13&version=NKJV) (thanks @Hawkeye!)

An evil ruler he was, kill an innocent child,

> Herod - [Matthew 2:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%202%3A16&version=CSB)

The little boy, so tender and mild.

> Jesus - [Silent Night](https://genius.com/Christmas-songs-silent-night-lyrics), line 4

A man and a wall, helps make it stand,

> Nehemiah - [Nehemiah 2:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Nehemiah+2%3A17&version=CSB)

A queen, so brave, helps people across her land.

> Queen Esther - [Esther 7:3-4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Esther+7%3A3-4&version=CSB)

A woman, so poor, had great luck with love,

> Ruth - [Ruth 2:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ruth+2%3A7&version=CSB) and [Ruth 4:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ruth+4%3A13&version=CSB)

Another one, within a falling city, was saved, as sweet as a dove.

> Rahab - [Joshua 6:24-25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua+6%3A24-25&version=CSB)

Now you have heard, so tell me this,
Who are these people, all ye Misters and Miss?

> These people are all people mentioned in the Bible

Comment: Beat me to it! Although I believe "A boy, called to Him, so young," and "3 more men held their tongue" are part of the same description about the young man who rebuked `Job` and his three friends. So I think `Job` is the answer for that one.

Comment: I don't know if Job was explicitly called to God when he was young whereas Samuel was, but I agree with the second part, especially with the concrete "three"; guess we'll have wait for feedback from @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica on this one

Comment: Never mind - I see that you're talking about Elihu for the first part, which tracks, but I think the "called" part of it fits better with Samuel

Comment: All correct! Just waiting for the last one for that last line before the check comes!

Comment: And I was refering to rot 13(gur guerr jvfr zra) in the hold tongue part

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying. Yeah, perhaps you're right.

Answer (score 1):

The third one:

> A shepherd, in the wild, a stick to a snake

Is:

> Moses from the Bible

As it was said:

> God helped Moses (and his brother) to free the Israelites from Egypt. One of the things Moses did was turning a stick into snake.

Here is the the verse:

> (Exodus chapter 4, verse 2) When God appears to Moses in the burning bush, God asks what Moses has in his hand, and Moses answers "a staff" ("a rod" in the King James Version). The staff is then miraculously transformed into a snake and then back into a staff.

Comment: Rot13(Bar bs gur guvatf Noenunz qvq?)